# Writing SAPUI5 control renderer in "sap.ui.define" style

Tags: sapui5

I'd like to write custom control in a new `sap.ui.define` fashion. I have a problem implementing control renderer in a separate file: it seems one have to put `bExport = true`, while this is [forbidden by SAP](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.html#.define).

> bExport: whether an export to global names is required - should be used by SAP-owned code only

I haven't found any examples of renderer implementations that doesn't utilize export hack and I have a doubt if such a way ever exists.

I've got some suggestions, but they doesn't fully satisfy me:

- Ignore SAP requirement and use `bExport = true`. Pros: highest reuse of SAP code and generally follow standard logic. Cons: avoiding official recommendations.
- Explicitly set `my.namespace.control.GreatControlRenderer` from within factory function. Pros: simple, doesn't touch `bExport`. Cons: breaks modular design (as module actually sets global variable).

What is the best or recommended way to resolve this issue?

---

Technically, an object reference available for public use is created inside framework code with [`jQuery.sap.setObject`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/45f5d14fb4dbf5f05599d636864593ee6028351f/src/sap.ui.core/src/jquery.sap.global.js#L1282) method, both in:

1. `sap.ui.core.Control.extend()` -- actually within parent class method
   [`sap.ui.base.Metadata.createClass()`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/base/Metadata.js#L362)
2. [`sap.ui.define(/* bExport = */ true)`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/45f5d14fb4dbf5f05599d636864593ee6028351f/src/sap.ui.core/src/jquery.sap.global.js#L3731)

This method creates hierarchy of objects in global scope by object `dot.separated.qualified.name` as follows:

```
jQuery.sap.setObject = function(sName, vValue, oContext) {
  var oObject = oContext || window,
      aNames = (sName || "").split("."),
      l = aNames.length,
      i;

  if (l > 0) {
    for (i = 0; oObject && i < l - 1; i++) {
      if (!oObject[aNames[i]]) {
        oObject[aNames[i]] = {};
      }
      oObject = oObject[aNames[i]];
    }
    oObject[aNames[l - 1]] = vValue;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your Renderer is an Object with a render function. It's a static function. Return this Renderer from your module.

```js
sap.ui.define([], function(){
  "use strict";
  var MyControlRenderer = {};
  MyControlRenderer.apiVersion = 2;
  MyControlRenderer.render = function(oRm, oControl){
    // Render your control
  };
  return MyControlRenderer;
});
```

Then in your control, you import your Renderer object and assign it to the renderer property of your control like this:

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/Control",
  "./MyControlRenderer"
], function(Control, MyControlRenderer) {
  "use strict";
  var MyControl = Control.extend("bla.MyControl", {
    metadata: {
      // ...
    },
    renderer: MyControlRenderer
  });
  return MyControl;
});
```

In this example the renderer is in the same directory as the control.

Comment: For other readers: there was a bug in UI5 where a non-existing `*Renderer.js` file was being fetched if the control extended from an abstract class (e.g. sap/ui/core/TooltipBase*Renderer*.js doesn't exist). This is fixed now by commit [`50da9ee`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/50da9eedc2bf4a024694f2f84dd4c7c13cb2200c#diff-ccdc8c28997607c380f9f137a6dc8777R98) and [`270661e`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/270661ed5a57468eec67772db69a9ad16be9f818#diff-ccdc8c28997607c380f9f137a6dc8777) which should be available as of UI5 1.82.0+